# Does "Her hair was tied back in a neat bow." mean the ribbon in her hair is in a bow?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Does "Her hair was tied back in a neat bow." look like this picture when her hair is in a bow?

[image: back of a woman's head showing her hair made into a bow shape]

or look like this picture when she used the ribbon to tie her hair and the ribbon is in a bow?

[image: view of a woman's long hair showing the front section tied back with a ribbon]

Picture Credit: https://www.hairandmakeupbysteph.com/inquire

Comment: Usually it's the ribbon that's tied in a bow.

Comment: It's also common to say "Her hair was tied back in a ribbon", but you could use "with a bow/ribbon".

Comment: That top picture looks like a recipe for trouble!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, can I say "I tied the box in a bow"?

Comment: No, but you can say I tied a string or ribbon around the box with a bow.

Comment: Until I saw that picture of the hair itself formed into the shape of a bow, I would never have thought it was possible, and would have said, "Of course it's the ribbon, you fool." :-)    The words *in a neat bow* are  ambiguous. But until that hair-do becomes very popular, or the context is unusual hairdos, it is fairly safe to conclude the "bow" is *probably* some kind of ribbon or yarn.

Comment: I think it's the ribbon, but note, it's not the words that lead to this conclusion, but a cultural assumption of which practice is more common.

Comment: @TimR The hair itself is not tied in bow. It is merely put/brought together to look as if it were...

Comment: Tom: You need to provide links to the pictures which are copyright protected: Image credit: hairandmakeupbysteph And the link: https://www.bebeautiful.in/all-things-hair/everyday/how-to-do-the-half-tied-bow-hairdo Please stop posting these questions with pictures without attribution. It is plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

*Her hair was tied back in a bow* commonly conveys “by means of a bow (made of ribbon or the like).” It can equally idiomatically be restated as *Her hair was tied back **with** a bow*.

It wouldn’t be wrong to use your sentence to describe your first photo, but that interpretation would come as a surprise to most listeners or readers. To describe the situation shown in the photo, one would normally say it differently. Maybe something like

- *Her hair was formed into a bow in back*
- *Her hair was done into a bow shape in back*, or
- *She wore her hair itself tied as a bow*.

These longer versions provide the more precise descriptions to highlight the unusualness of that hairstyle.

I hasten to add, though, that it’s perfectly idiomatic to say things like

- *Her hair was pulled back **in** a braid* and
- *She wore her hair tied back **in** a bun*.

But in those cases it’s understood that there’s no device involved. Just the hair itself.

Comment: Yes, but not: She wore her hair itself tied as a bow. It would not work because hair is too slippery for that. It is indeed formed or done into a bow.

Comment: Interesting assertion, @Lambie, in its being made unconditionally and in its being in error. My wife would happily tell you about the women she knows who could pull that sort of thing off (no pun intended) using nothing at all besides their natural hair.

Comment: See how she uses an elactic band? It cannot just be done with the person's hair. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jn_t4tSY-wQ The lady doing it even refers to the "top pony [tail]" and the botton one. Anyone who has had long hair knows this.

Comment: Why the need to express yourself so unconditionally, @Lambie? “It **cannot just** be done with the person’s hair”? “**Anyone** who has had long hair knows that”? Do you assert as a violation of the very laws of physics the possibility that two handfuls of some womens’ long hair can, just like two shoelaces, be formed into a bow? Do you have tribological data to support such an assertion? My wife does have empirical evidence from having observed women achieve similar feats.

Comment: Tom always asks questions which he believes will trip us up. If a bow could be tied using only the person's real hair, don't you think I would know about it, as I am a woman who had very long hair for many years, and that there would be "tons" of examples on Utube etc.? Empirical evidence? Goodness... **Hair is slippery and needs something to hold it in place** ....It will not stay in place **on its own**. Why does it annoy you that I might know more about long hair than you?

Comment: Why do you assume that your superior familiarity with some people’s hair annoys me? You know more about **your** long hair than I do. And that is a state of affairs with which I am quite at ease. You do not know more about the long hair of, for instance, my wife’s college friend.

Comment: Here is the site where the first picture above is taken from: https://www.bebeautiful.in/all-things-hair/everyday/how-to-do-the-half-tied-bow-hairdo See the elastic band? You can see it in the other images. The result is that it looks like nothing is holding it in place...

Comment: What interests—I wouldn’t say *annoys* —me, @Lambie, is your extrapolating from your unquestioned personal experience to a universal statement about everyone’s hair under every condition. The fact that the woman in that video did it that way does not imply that no person could do it in any other way.

Comment: On the contrary, I had to question myself in order to realize it can't be done without an elastic band or some other hair accoutrement.

Comment: But with how many people’s hair have you tried it, @lambie? And in what conditions? Unaltered? Recently dyed or bleached? Recently straightened? Were the people in their teens? In their nineties? Were they Nordic? American Indian? Maori? Bantu? You have universalized that **no** person can **ever** form their hair into a bow without some device like an elastic.  That is an exceptionally strong claim that would seem to preclude my wife’s classmate’s existence. If you are right, then her kid brother will instantly become sole heir to their parents’ estate.

Comment: Yes, *perhaps* a black person's hair but not a white one. What if, as a man, I said to you, he dresses down the middle? Wouldn't that make you laugh? Well, it's the same idea, for the (plagiarized until now; he still has not fixed that as of this comment) photos posted by the OP.

Comment: Okay, @Lambie, I’ll break the news to Cynthia that you have decreed her to be black.  All I said—way back in my answer—was “Maybe something like … *She wore her hair itself tied as a bow*.” Since you agree that some black person *might* do that, I guess we can call it a day.

Comment: I never mentioned the race of your wife. I said that possibly a black person's hair could be tied in bow. And I dispute that sentence and there is no point repeating it.

Comment: It’s actually my wife’s friend whose race is at issue here, @lambie. That plus the fact that she’s a blonde (and indeed Swedish) **and** possessed of highly capable hair. But not obviously black. Whatevs…